# How to avoid having the layer name in the field name?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes

I'm working with ArcMap 10. I might be doing something wrong but can't see what:
I want to add a field in an attribute table. Problem is that as I name it "FieldName" the resulting name in the header is "LayerName.FieldName". 
Why? How to avoid the layer name to be added in the field name?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have join of some kind to your layer. Then it makes sense to distinguish between the two layers' fields.

Comment: Yes It's a table resulting from a join. No way to avoid that? Old fields in the header appear as before joining, but if i create a new one I get the Layer name in.

Comment: I can't really see how that is a problem (is it?), but removing and recreating the join should restore the field names without layer name. As I said, it is by design so that  you can tell which layer a field actually is in, especially when you add fields since these are placed to the very right in your table.

Comment: It's not a big problem, I just wanted to be fussy with the names. I see what you say but don't quite understand why the other fields wouldn't show (in the header) the name of the layer they come from (see picture in edited question). I'm sure it's me confused about something.

Comment: You can search on "fully qualified field names" for more information on how to work around this.  See http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/geoprocessing_environments/an_overview_of_general_settings.htm and http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=986&t=278342&mc=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table joined when you create the field it will automatically add the layer name.  If you want to avoid this remove the join then create the field and rejoin the table.

Or you could right click the field and change the field alias to remove the layer name.